# How to filter "Query" in Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: android, database, kotlin, orm

I'm working on an Android application (Kotlin) where I have to connect the app with an already existing database (PostgreSQL). Right now I'm trying to do it with Jetbrains Exposed ORM, but I'm struggling in some parts, one of them is filtering the results obtained by "query".

I have one table called "User" and inside that table, there are multiple attributes such as Name, Height, etc... but I just need the "Username" attribute. I'm comparing it with the string "username" that I input. Basically, the query should search through the database and check if there is a matching username. So far I've been able to get it by using a FOR loop and .select{} as it can be seen in the code down below:

```
for (user in User.select{
                User.username eq username
            }){
                println(user[User.username])
            }
```

However, I'm not sure if that's the best way so I'm trying to do it with a "query" as you can see down below:

```
val query = User.select({User.username eq username})
            println(query)
```

The problem is, if I do it this way, the only thing I'm going to see is "org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Query@7e809b79" as the output. That looks like the output is actually the whole "User" object and not just the "username" part.

My question is, how do I "filter" the query variable so that I can output the actual "username"? I've gone through the Exposed documentation and tried to experiment a bit, but can't wrap my head around it, pretty sure it's something simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the exposed DAO approach it might look like

`User.all().forEach{user->println(user.username)}`

assuming you have connected to your database and
have a transaction open